# Unable to activate instance of type NavigationPageRenderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, master-detail

I have a MasterDetailPage and this page get pushed to a Navigation:

```
await MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MasterDevicePage());
```

when the master device page get loaded, the master page's list view will then select one of the page and display it on the detail screen.

```
masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageModel;
            if (item != null)
            {
                Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
                Detail.Title = item.Title;
                masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented = false;
            }
        };
```

The error occurs at the Detail = new NavigationPage part.

> No constructor found for
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer::.ctor(System.IntPtr,
>   Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)
>
> Unable to activate instance of type
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer from
>   native handle 0x85300019 (key_handle 0x42c360f8).

Comment: have you looked at: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40258?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to fix it supplying constructor

```
public YourClass (IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base ()
        {
        }
```

BUT
MasterDetailPage should be never pushed to Navigation stack.

Comment: ThankS i use Mr. L 's link which lead me to https://gist.github.com/SeeD-Seifer/ff8b522f7e8b55ec719f68e1765b0314, Which have a renderer class which solve the problem.

Comment: This worked for error "Unable to activate instance of type    from native handle xamarin android" for custom control initialization