# Xamarin Form: MasterDetailPage: Does the detail page have to be NavigationPage as a standard

Tags: xamarin, navigation-drawer, master-detail

In the sample code from Xamarin website, the Detail page was added to a NavigationPage

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(new TestPage());
```

Does TestPage have to be wrapped by NavigationPage? If I remove NavigationPage and just put `new TestPage()`, it will work on me. If I keep NavigationPage in, I have the error which I have posted in here.

[Reference from my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419574/xamarin-form-unable-to-activate-instance-of-type-navigationpagerenderer)

If without NavigationPage, the hamburger icon will be gone, even though still able to show the master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From official Xamarin documentation:](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/)

```
Public Constructors

NavigationPage()
Initializes a new NavigationPage object.

NavigationPage(Page) 
Creates a new NavigationPage element with root as its root element.
```

So you only need/want/have to pass a page as argument if you want to specify that it's a root element.

Also in case you developing an UWP app with MasterDetailPage you should keep in mind:

[Generally, you'll set these two properties to objects of type
ContentPage, but currently, to get MasterDetailPage to work on the
Universal Windows Platform, the detail page **must be a NavigationPage**.](https://download.xamarin.com/developer/xamarin-forms-book/XamarinFormsBook-Ch25-Apr2016.pdf)